# BibTex Chicago Style: Is it possible to have different page numbers in the footnotes and bibligraphy?

Tags: bibtex, biblatex-chicago, chicago-style

I am relatively new to Latex and I am trying to integrate Chicago style footnotes and bibliography using BibTex.

I managed to create the separate .bib file and include both footnotes and bibliography using the appropriate style.

I am referencing a book for testing purposes and I could get the correct format in the footnote.
The bibliography for the same book looks good except for the pages property. Is there a way to reassign the page numbering to the bibliography section?

I would like to have the exact page number in the footnote and the chapter range in the bibliography for the same book.

This is my current setup for the main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in, ]{geometry}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}


\begin{document}

  \section{Abstract} 

    This is some dummy text \autocite{test}

  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is my current setup for the bibliography.bib file:

```
@incollection{test,
  author      = "Henry David Thoreau",
  title       = "Walking",
  editor      = "John D’Agata",
  booktitle   = "The Making of the American Essay",
  publisher   = "Graywolf Press",
  address     = "Minneapolis",
  year        = 2016,
  pages       = "177-78"
 }
```

From this I get the following output:

**The footnote section:**
[image]

**The References section:**
[image]

How can I change the pages number on the References section, leaving the footnote pages number untouched?

I would like to have 177-178 on the footnote and 177-200 on the References.
All keeping the exact Chicago style order.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

The `pages` field in the `.bib` file should always contain the full page range of the article/chapter/... the entry refers to.

The page range (pinpoint reference) for a particular citation should be given in the postnote argument of the `\autocite`/`\cite`/`\parencite` command.

```
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}      % only postnote
\autocite[Cf.][380]{sigfridsson} % pre- and postnote
\autocite[Cf.][]{sigfridsson}    % only prenote
```

If you want the page ranges to be compressed, you should load `biblatex-chicago` with the `compresspages` options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in, ]{geometry}

\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,compresspages,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{test,
  author      = {Henry David Thoreau},
  title       = {Walking},
  editor      = {John D’Agata},
  booktitle   = {The Making of the American Essay},
  publisher   = {Graywolf Press},
  address     = {Minneapolis},
  year        = 2016,
  pages       = {177-200},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \null\vfill % just for the example

  Lorem \autocite[177-178]{test}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation: "Henry David Thoreau, “Walking,” in The Making of the American Essay, ed. John D’Agata (Minneapolis: Graywolf Press, 2016), 177–78."//Bibliography "Thoreau, Henry David. “Walking.” In The Making of the American Essay, edited by John D’Agata, 177–200. Minneapolis: Graywolf Press, 2016."]